# Updating two form inputs from 1 input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, paypal

I usually work in VBScript, but I'm trying to help a friend with some javascript and I keep hitting syntax errors.  I'm working on a PayPal link, and I'm trying to update an amount based on a quantity field.

Javascript portion:

```
<script language="javascript">
function updateQTY() {
   var Qty = document.getElementByID('quantity');
   var vshowCost = document.getElementByID('showCost');
   var vpostCost = document.getElementByID('postCost'); 
   vshowCost.value=parsefloat(Qty.value)*100;
   vpostCost.value=parsefloat(Qty.value)*100;
   return 1;
}​
</script>
```

HTML form code:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="consulting" id="consulting">
    <tr class="StoreFront">
        <td class="StoreFront">
            <b>Consulting
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="4" onchange="updateQty();" value="2">
            Cost: $<input type="text" name="showCost" id="showCost" value="200" size="8" readonly>CAD
        </td>
        <td class="StoreFront" valign="top" width="130px">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            <input type="hidden" id="postCost" name="amount" value="0.00">
            <br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

I'm getting an invalid token error at the closing curly brace. Any ideas?

Comment: when copy-pasting your snippet, there's a weird char right after the closing curly bracket: charCode 8203

Comment: As Thomas says, I noticed this when I pasted it into CodePen. Pretty sure thats the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that Javascript is case sensitive. There are many errors in your javascript function. Try it:

```
function updateQty() {
   var Qty = document.getElementById('quantity');
   var vshowCost = document.getElementById('showCost');
   var vpostCost = document.getElementById('postCost');
   vshowCost.value = parseFloat(Qty.value)*100;
   vpostCost.value = parseFloat(Qty.value)*100;
}
```